# Getting started with http media streaming in C

Tags: c, http, http-streaming

Alrighty so, I've been wanting to learn C for awhile, and now I have a project idea that's actually relevant to a website I want to build, but I have a few initial questions on how to get started. This isn't really a "how to program" question or anything, I can get started with C programming fine, I know how to read and communicate with various APIs and protocols as long as I have documentation, etc. I'm just looking for a starting point, I guess.

The program would be something similar to ice or shoutcast, so basically audio streaming. Does anyone think they could give a brief, high-level overview of what would be required? As I said the end product would be a url you pop in a .pls file and you can stream it to w/e client you want. What protocols, libraries, and documentation should I be looking at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this to be a toy for learning, you might want to do all the work yourself; it's a complicated problem, and getting it *right* is definitely going to be educational. A copy of [Advanced Programming the Unix Environment, 2nd edition](http://www.apuebook.com/) or [TCP/IP Illustrated, Vol 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP_Illustrated#Volume_1%3a_The_Protocols) would be helpful but not strictly necessary.

If you want this to be useful too, I'd suggest starting with [`libev`](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html) or [`libevent`](http://libevent.org/). `libevent` has some built-in HTTP handling, which might be nice, but [there are reports that `libevent`s HTTP handling isn't perfect](http://blog.gevent.org/2011/04/28/libev-and-libevent/). `libev` doesn't provide built-in HTTP handling, but it should be easier to write with `libev` than performing all the work by hand. Using these pre-written event-based libraries will improve the stability and reliability of your program compared to writing the entire thing by hand, though they aren't doing anything that you can't do yourself.